# Comparing an inertial frame with a non-inertial frame, how to know which is inertial and which is non-inertial just by looking at the relative motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I recently asked this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/685601/is-the-sensation-of-apparent-acceleration-within-the-frame-or-visible-force-sour/685609#685609) about whether apparent acceleration is enough on its own to know if the frame is non-inertial, and the answer is in fact yes. But now the question is:

Two wagons are moving, one in a straight line and the other accelerating. If an observer is within either of the two, how can he know whether he is inertial or not, if the observer's perception of the effect of apparent gravity is disregarded (very small acceleration, for example) and in the absence of any suspended object in the ceiling, or any loose and frictionless object in the wagon, and also in the absence of any accelerometer, just observing the relative movement between the two wagons... is it possible to make a statement under the conditions?

Comment: You seem to be asking whether it is possible to observe the acceleration of a frame when everything is rigidly fixed in place in that frame.  In that case, the answer is no, because you have disallowed all motion and thus all in-frame measurements, a priori.

Comment: @Buzz In fact, they are not fixed, the observer does not know which one is accelerated and inserted in either one of the two, without being able to feel the action of the apparent acceleration, a single source of information is the vision of relative motion, only with this it is possible to know which is inertial and non-inertial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By excluding accelerometers you have made it indeterminate since any principle that you could use to distinguish the two would qualify as an accelerometer. This says nothing about the physics and is purely an ignorance due to the artificial limitations given in the scenario.

This is like asking if you can measure temperature without a thermometer. No, because any method that you could use to measure temperature would be a thermometer. Similarly with most other physical quantities.